# Fail to install R packages in DashDB/RStudio/Bluemix : wget: command not found

Tags: rstudio, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am trying to install rjson, httpuv packages in RStudio in dashDB with following command:
install.packages(c("rjson", "httpuv"))

I got the following message: 
**sh: wget: command not found** 
Warning in install.packages :
  download had nonzero exit status

I can't install wget myself since I have no root permission.  Is there any workaround for this problem? Will wget be built-in in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new dashDB service (Published on: 2016-0414). The issue no longer exist. I can install the package I want now.